# How to access a server running inside genymotion emulator from my computer?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I've installed the [SimpleHTTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ubi.common.http.server&hl=en) app on my Genymotion emulator (Google Nexus 9 - 5.1.0 - API 22).

The app created a HTTP server on Android and allows you to access the phone with a browser using the following URLs:

1. http://10.0.3.15:12345/
2. http://192.168.56.101:12345/

Now I can access these URLs with the Android browser inside the emulator but when I try to access them from outside the emulator using my browser (Windows) I get a connection error / 404.

**How can I connect to the ServerSocket on Android from outside the emulator?**

---

P.S. I can access the Apache server (installed on Computer / Windows) from the Genymotion emulator using http://192.168.56.1/ or http://10.0.3.2, but there is no way to access the HTTP server running inside Genymotion emulator from Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following to get it working

adb forward tcp:[host port] tcp:[virtual device port]

From [here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support#faq)